# Redirecting to the edited page in response to edit

Tags: php

I am looking for a PHP Script that would redirect the user see his own page/record after he has saved his edits. e.g. client logs on finds his record clicks to edits his record and once he saves his record the page will redirect to view his changes. I am using PHPRunner. According to the instructions I would add a script to the After Edit Events: Redirect tab and add a script. The only problem I am having is that I don't know the script needed to fetch the records Key. Below is a sample of what I saw in a previous post. A little different for it is more of a button. But based on this script I figured I can make it work. Can anyone help? The TABLE: Teams Key: TID

I have an idea based on what I have seen.

```
//**********  Redirect to another page  ************
header("Location: Teams_view.php?editid1=key1=".$keys["TID"]);

exit();
```

But this will not send the client to its own page. Then I have seen this but it does not fetch the record id(Key) either.

```
header("Location: Teams.php?key1=".$keys["TID"]);

exit();
```

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Answer (score 1):

As long as no content has been sent (echo, etc), this will always work.

```
$qid = "10627129";
$url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/$qid";   // Fully-qualified URL

// Uncomment this when debugging.
//echo "About to redirect to: $url";  exit();

header("Location: $url");
exit();
```